# How to get the python color value for a RGB tuple

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot graphs in a specific color. Is there a way to convert a RGB tuple, for example (188,32,75) in such a way that I can use it as a python color?

I tried

```
plt.plot(X,Y,marker='d',color=(188,32,75))
```

but I get an error, that RGB/A values should be in [0,1].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just divide your color codes by 255 to bring them in the `[0,1]` range required

```
plt.plot(X,Y,marker='d',color=(188/255.0, 32/255.0, 75/255.0))
```